# Dropbox - IOS- Swift 3 : Cannot get the thumbnail image

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox, dropbox-api, swiftydropbox

I am trying to populate my collection view with images from the dropbox.

I want to have the thumbnail image for my grid view (collection view) with the following code.

```
DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient?.files.getThumbnail(path: filename).response(completionHandler: { (
            response, error) in

            print(response)
            print(error)

})
```

I get the following error:

```
Optional([request-id e70dba3b7ee8f0b9bf6b0aa4b19325f0] API route error - {
".tag" = path;
path =     {
    ".tag" = "not_found";
};
})
```

But when I try to getthumbnail using this following method I get error .I don't know which url i should return to this function:

```
DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient?.files.getThumbnail(path: filename, format: .png, size: .w32h32, overwrite: true, destination: { (url, res) -> URL in

            print(url)
            print(res)
            return url
        })
```

**UPDATE:
CAN'T WE GET THUMBNAIL URL FOR DROPBOX IMAGES IN IOS?**

Does anyone has the solution ?

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a thumbnail for a file in Dropbox using the [API v2 Swift SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox), using one of the [`getThumbnail` methods](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/FilesRoutes.html#/s:FC13SwiftyDropbox11FilesRoutes12getThumbnailFT4pathSS6formatOCS_5Files15ThumbnailFormat4sizeOS1_13ThumbnailSize9overwriteSb11destinationFTV10Foundation3URLCSo15HTTPURLResponse_S5__GCS_19DownloadRequestFileCS1_22FileMetadataSerializerCS1_24ThumbnailErrorSerializer_) is the correct approach.

For [`getThumbnail(path:format:size:overwrite:destination:)`](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/FilesRoutes.html#/s:FC13SwiftyDropbox11FilesRoutes12getThumbnailFT4pathSS6formatOCS_5Files15ThumbnailFormat4sizeOS1_13ThumbnailSize9overwriteSb11destinationFTV10Foundation3URLCSo15HTTPURLResponse_S5__GCS_19DownloadRequestFileCS1_22FileMetadataSerializerCS1_24ThumbnailErrorSerializer_), note that this will write the thumbnail data to the URL you specify. (I.e., it doesn't provide an Internet-accessible URL where the thumbnail data is hosted.)

The [`getThumbnail(path:format:size:overwrite:destination:)`](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/FilesRoutes.html#/s:FC13SwiftyDropbox11FilesRoutes12getThumbnailFT4pathSS6formatOCS_5Files15ThumbnailFormat4sizeOS1_13ThumbnailSize9overwriteSb11destinationFTV10Foundation3URLCSo15HTTPURLResponse_S5__GCS_19DownloadRequestFileCS1_22FileMetadataSerializerCS1_24ThumbnailErrorSerializer_) method is a download-style request, so you should use it as shown under ["Download-style request" in the readme](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox#download-style-request), per the "Download to URL" example.

The [`getThumbnail(path:format:size:)`](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/FilesRoutes.html#/s:FC13SwiftyDropbox11FilesRoutes12getThumbnailFT4pathSS6formatOCS_5Files15ThumbnailFormat4sizeOS1_13ThumbnailSize_GCS_21DownloadRequestMemoryCS1_22FileMetadataSerializerCS1_24ThumbnailErrorSerializer_) method will return the thumbnail data in memory. You would use it as shown under ["Download-style request" in the readme](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox#download-style-request), per the "Download to Data" example.

In either case, note that the `path/not_found` error you're getting is referring to the `path: filename` parameter you're supplying. That is, there is nothing found at that path in the Dropbox account. You should specify the remote Dropbox path of the file that you want a thumbnail for.

Comment: Do you got sample code regarding using API v2 swift sdk? I am really blank on this .

Comment: There's a [sample app](https://github.com/dropbox/PhotoWatch) you can refer to, but it looks like you already managed to write the `getTemporaryLink` call, per [your new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890727/ios-collectionview-images-disappear-on-scrolling-and-sometimes-overlaps).

Comment: Thanks and a very big thanks . I can download the thumbnails of size 32*32 and of any size . 
 Thank you so much for your precious time.

But I have a problem , my collection view cell images disappear on scrolling . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890727/ios-collectionview-images-disappear-on-scrolling-and-sometimes-overlaps/43891043?noredirect=1#comment74818329_43891043